# Using Plotly Drop-down Widget with bar graph

Tags: python, plotly

I have been trying to apply a drop-down widget on a bar chart I made, but I am having trouble applying the filter. I have been using this documentation guide:

https://plot.ly/python/dropdown-widget/

Now, I have a dataset setup like this:

```
id    happiness_score   time_of_day   
01             3                    08
02             4                    16
03             1                    22
04             2                    03
05             5                    16
```

I am trying to create a bar graph, with the score as the x-axis, and count of Id as the y-axis, and the time of day as the dropdown widget.

so far I’ve been able to create the widget, which took a bit of time, but here is how I got it:

```
#make a copy of the original df
df2 = df1


#converting the score to an object
df1['survey_time'] = 1['surveyed_at']= pd.to_datetime(dfnoadmin['surveyed_at'])
df1['survey_time'] = df1.survey_time.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%H'))
df1['score'] = df1['score'].apply(str)
df1.dtypes

#for the widget

dfq = df1
# we will define a function that will handle the input from the dropdown widget
def update_plot(dfz):
    noadmin = dfq['score'] ==  dfz['new']
    temp = dfq[noadmin]
    data = temp.groupby(dfq['score'])['time_of_day'].count()

    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        x.append(data.index[i])
        y.append(data[i])

    graph.restyle({
                'x': [x],
                'y': [y],
            })
    graph.relayout({'title': 'blah of {} blah'.format(dfz['new'])})

w = widgets.Dropdown(
    options= list(dfq['score'].unique()),
    value='0',
    description='score',
)

#now for graphing`
#turn the score back to an int for organizational purposes    


df2['score'] = df2['score'].apply(int)
fq = df2
fq = fq.groupby(['survey_time']).agg({'id': 'count'})


x= fq['id'].nlargest(400)
data1 = [Bar(
            y=x,
            x=x.keys(),
            text=x,
            textposition = 'outside',
            marker = dict(
            color = 'rgba(158,202,225)',
                line=dict(
                    color='rgb(8,48,107)',
                    width=1.5),
            ),
            name = "Total Users",
            opacity=0.6
    )]

layout1 = go.Layout(
    title="Time of Day",
    xaxis=dict(
        title='Surveys Completed by the hour',
        titlefont=dict(
            family='Courier New, monospace',
            size=18,
            color='#7f7f7f'
        )
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title='Time of Day',
        titlefont=dict(
            family='Courier New, monospace',
            size=18,
            color='#7f7f7f'
        )
    )
)

#Execute

display(w)

myFigure2 = go.Figure(data = data1 , layout = layout1)
iplot(myFigure2)
```

However, all it does is ignore the filter, and graphs all the ids across the day, regardless of the score. If I group dataframe fq by surveytime AND score, then count the ids, then nothing appears.

How can I apply the drop down filters to the graph I made?

Comment: i would be happy to help. But: please provide  something we can reproduce(https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for example, give us the right DataFrame with the right names on the columns. also i don't see the `w.observe(update_plot, names="selected_label")` in your code, did you have it when you test the code?

Answer (score 1):

Dev team at Plotly got back to me.

here is what they said

> We’re still working to clean out the old documentation, but the
>   GraphWidget approach in that page is not the recommended approach at
>   this point. The FigureWidget approach in plotly.py version 3 is much
>   more capable and reliable.
>
> I think the example in this page would be a good starting for you
>   using FigureWidget: https://plot.ly/python/figurewidget-app/ 2
>
> Hope that helps get you going,